# HtmlAgilityPack is being slow

Tags: c#

`HtmlAgilityPack` is being really slow pulling back results. I have seen similar tools that get results a lot faster, but it's taking over a minute just to get the viewcounts on YouTube, and that's just with the first page of results.

Ideally I want to loop through multiple elements, but a nested loop wouldn't work for this code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //webBrowser1.Navigate("www.youtube.com/results?search_query=grindtime");
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    string raw = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=grindtime";
    HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    webGet.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; I; Intel Mac OS X 11_7_9; de-LI; rv:1.9b4) Gecko/2012010317 Firefox/10.0a4";
    var document = webGet.Load(raw);
    var viewcount = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='viewcount']");
    //var videotitle = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='yt-uix-tile-link']");
    //var browser = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='viewcount']");

    if (viewcount != null)
    {
        foreach (var v in viewcount)
        {
             output.AppendLine(v.InnerHtml);

             ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("#1");
             lvi.SubItems.Add("video title here");
             lvi.SubItems.Add(b.InnerHtml);
             //views
             //desc..
             //lid = link in desc yes/no
             listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
         }
     }
```

[image]

Comment: How long does the `webGet.Load(raw);` take? IO (be it disk, network, etc) will always be the slowest part of your code.

Comment: Seems that the URL he is using is responding well. I cant imagine what 'b' from "b.InnerHtml" is. Maybe it is a huge HTML :D

Comment: about over a minute, I don't know if its a youtube thing or not but google and other places are just as slow. (I also tried my own page)@programad ignore the comments b used to be browser :)

Comment: @programad - The URL may be responding well for you but I'd imagine user1148562 is not sitting next to you at the moment.

Comment: @user1148562 - That seems ridiculously slow to me. Looks like you found your bottleneck.

Comment: If other sites are slow too, maybe there is no problem in your code, just your internet connection.

Comment: no the site works just fine, it just parses the html slow in the program, I have very fast internet.

Comment: @user1148562 - Now that you've identified that HTMLAgilityPack's attempt to load your page is the slowest part of your program, what is the question?

Comment: @M.Babcock basically I wanted to know how to make it go faster, I'm sure it will be even slower when I append all the pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the web request itself will take some time.

To be able to profile it, maybe do some test with opening saved HTML file instead, to make sure that the parsing is your actual bottleneck, maybe even commenting the lines that create the result UI as well.

I haven't used HTML Agility Pack much, but I see you are using an XPATH selector there, and it only uses a CSS Class. I'd assume the path will scan the entire document to check eevery element in it if it has the desired class or not.

So, it may be a good idea to try to add some parents to the selector, so that it only looks for elements inside a given parent, best selected by ID or a tag. Those are general rules for browsers, I don't expect them to work the same with HTML Agility Pack, but they may provide some gain still.
Also, check if there are any options in the library to match a single element, and if so, find that element and go through its children till you find your desired elements. This may improve things. Also, if there are any strict mode or less tolerant parsing options, try turning those on if they don't break the parsing.

If you expect the page to be well structured and HTML valid, and parsing speed isn't getting any better however you enhance the selector, you may consider reverting to classic old Regex matching.

Also, I recommend separating the Windows Forms rendering from the loop. Maybe the bottleneck is the drawing (unlikely, but maybe), try to add all your elements to a list, and then outside the loop, add the list to the windows forms control.

Comment: yes! i think this is the problem, but I thought the xpath I had was selecting every span tag with the class of viewcount. I used the same thing with haptestbed and it wasn't slow at all.

Comment: Cool. I hope this has solved the problem you were looking to solve them :)

Comment: yes, you was right, the xpath was causing it to be slow so i changed it to //body//span[@class='viewcount'] now it only takes about 5 seconds to parse those elements :) Im going to work on that path and make it faster though. I assume it was loading the scripts with the path I had.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a simple regex on the page result would be most certainly more efficient, though several people will tell you that using an *HTML parser* to parse *HTML* is always the best practice.

Comment: Although regex may seem fit for this kind of tasks, in the end it may lead to vary complex implementations that still don't cover all possible cases. I've seen such a case once and I can say that while the regex was so complicated it was hard to maintain, the AgilityPack implementation was trivial and 100% accurate.

Comment: Agreed but if performance is the OP primary (or possibly *only*) focus then a proper RegEx would be more appropriate.

Comment: I noticed that the first search is extremely slow, but the second search is pretty rapid, maybe if I load the search results page before the actual searches are done, this way when people get to the search page, the results page has already been loaded.

Comment: @chuckakers Are you still encountering performance problems despite the answer provided?

Comment: yes im going to try preloading the page before parsing the html, I notice it is really fast on any second or future searches, its just the first search that is slow.

Comment: @chuckakers - You'll need to either mark this question as unanswered (uncheck the checkbox on the answer you've selected) and update your question with *relevant* facts based on your findings (including updated source code); *or* ask another question (probably here on CR). Either way be sure to post your most recent source code exemplifying the problem.

Comment: ill mark it as answered and try the suggestions out before posting a follow up question.. thanks.