# Downloading HTML documents from the web

Tags: performance, vb.net, url

In this project I'm working on, I need to extract articles text from their original HTML document. This class, `HtmlConnection`, receives the URL of the article, and eventually it needs to produce a collection of the paragraphs inside the article. I'm using HTML agility pack and XPath to extract only relevent text from the article, "removing" irrelevant text that comes alongside in the HTML, such as JavaScript, etc. Notice that this class does not produce the final text of the article (another class deals with it), but rather a `HtmlNodeCollection` that consist of all the paragraphs in the article.

There is one main issue in the code: It's too slow.

I did some test, and came up with these numbers:

- Number of articles downloaded: 25
- Average download time: 4958 Miliseconds

This is too much. As you can see, just 25 articles take about 2 minutes. And I plan to download hundreds of articles per run. It could be a problem with my internet connection, but when I'm surfing normally, it's pretty fast and clean.

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Net

''' <summary>
''' Represents a single Html document.
''' </summary>
Public Class HtmlConnection

    ' XPath for all the paragraphs inside the body.
    Private Const BodyPath As String = "//body//p"

    ' RegEx for a single word.
    Private Const WordPath As String = "[a-zA-Z]+"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Constructor to initialize Url property
    ''' and to call the DownloadHtml sub.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="url">
    ''' The Url of the current article.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal url As String)

        Me.Url = url
        DownloadHtml()

    End Sub ' Constructor

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Represents the Url of the current article.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Property Url As String
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Represents all the Html code 
    ''' received from the article.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Property FullHtml As HtmlDocument

    Private _BodyHtml As HtmlNodeCollection
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Represents the Html of all the paragraph inside the body.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property BodyHtml As HtmlNodeCollection
        Get
            Return _BodyHtml
        End Get
        Set(value As HtmlNodeCollection)

            Dim WordsMatches As MatchCollection
            _BodyHtml = value

            ' Iterate through all the paragraphs in order to 
            ' count the number of words in them. We assume that a 
            ' paragraph should be more then 10 words at least in order 
            ' to be considered as part of the article, and not as an 
            ' irrelevant text, such as the name of the author or a date,
            ' which are usually presented in an independent paragraph.
            ' We operate in a descending order to prevent wrong 
            ' filtration or an "index was out of range" error.
            For Paragraph As Integer = value.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                WordsMatches = Regex.Matches(value.Item(Paragraph).InnerText, WordPath)
                If WordsMatches.Count < 10 Then
                    _BodyHtml.RemoveAt(Paragraph)
                End If
            Next

        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new Html DOM using XPath.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub DownloadHtml()

        ' HtmlWeb uses Http protocol to download
        ' Html documents according to a certain Url.
        Dim HtmlWeb As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
        FullHtml = New HtmlDocument

        ' Because BodyHtml is a collection, it needs to be
        ' initialize. Thus, we create a new HtmlNodeColleciton
        ' that does not actually possess any nodes, but now
        ' we can add to it new elements without causing an
        ' "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.
        _BodyHtml = New HtmlNodeCollection(FullHtml.DocumentNode)
        FullHtml = (HtmlWeb.Load(Url))

        ' Fix any nodes error that may
        ' occur inside the html code.
        FullHtml.OptionFixNestedTags = True

        BodyHtml = FullHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(BodyPath)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I switched your tag to remove C# and add performance instead. I'm sure someone will be able to review it in the native language.

Comment: Duplicate of http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7827/htmlagilitypack-is-being-slow?

Comment: Make sure that it's the actual downloading that is slow. If it is, then you can't do much except add 2-3 threads.

Comment: @the_lotus I'm almost certain that the bottleneck is the downloading of the html. I though of using multiple threads, but the problem is that i've never used multithreading nor learend about it deeply. Can you give me a few advices on how should I do that?

Comment: In your case, I would have a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)). Start 4 threads that add the pages information into the FIFO and have the main thread check the FIFO for anything that needs to be parsed. If you want to reduce bandwidth (especially for the person you are downloading from), have two process, one that downloads the files in the harddrive with threads. And a second process that parses the files anything you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down your code and look at what you're doing wrong/right and what can be improved.

---

**I** - Class

> ```
> Public Class HtmlConnection
> ```

The name of your class is quite misleading as it's not a connection object as per se. It's an object which *contains* html. The underlying `HttpClient` used in HAP is closer to being (if not is) a html connector. So we'll rename the class so that it reflects what it is/represents, a html article.

```
Public Class HtmlArticle
```

**II** - Constants

> ```
> Private Const BodyPath As String = "//body//p"
> Private Const WordPath As String = "[a-zA-Z]+"
> ```

This is good! You're using constants instead of magic strings/numbers. Nothing to change here except that I'll introduce a new constant.

```
Private Const MinLength As Integer = 10
```

**III**  - Fields

> ```
> Private _BodyHtml As HtmlNodeCollection
> ```

Fields should be placed at the top and written in [lowerCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). It's also a bad habit to start a member name with an [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195030/why-is-this-name-with-an-underscore-not-cls-compliant) as this makes your code non [CLS compliant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/12a7a7h3(v=vs.100).aspx) if the member is anything other than private.

We'll rename the member and introduce a new one. I'll explain *why* later.

```
Private m_url As String
Private m_paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection
```

**IV** - Constructors

> ```
> Public Sub New(ByVal url As String)
>     Me.Url = url
>     DownloadHtml()
> End Sub
> ```

You're doing a very big mistake in the constructor. It's doing too much work. Constructors should be as [light as possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229060(v=vs.100).aspx). The html should only be downloaded when needed, when you decide to invoke `DownloadHtml`. Same logic applies for the [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It doesn't invoke `Open`in the constructor. You have to do this as a separate call.

Your casing is correct but you can remove the `ByVal` keyword as this is default by design. I'll introduce a new parameter and make the constructor private. More about that later.

```
Private Sub New(url As String, paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection)
    Me.m_url = url
    Me.m_paragraphs = paragraphs
End Sub
```

**V** - Properties

> ```
> Private Property Url As String
>
> Private Property FullHtml As HtmlDocument
>
> Public Property BodyHtml As HtmlNodeCollection
>     Get
>         Return _BodyHtml
>     End Get
>     Set(value As HtmlNodeCollection)
>
>         Dim WordsMatches As MatchCollection
>         _BodyHtml = value
>
>         For Paragraph As Integer = value.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
>             WordsMatches = Regex.Matches(value.Item(Paragraph).InnerText, WordPath)
>             If WordsMatches.Count < 10 Then
>                 _BodyHtml.RemoveAt(Paragraph)
>             End If
>         Next
>
>     End Set
> End Property
> ```

Private auto-implemented get-set properties should always be turned into fields.

You should avoid heavy code in properties. Properties should mainly be used to get and set the value of a backing field, not processing data. The code should be moved to the `DownloadHtml` method.

The expression `WordsMatches.Count < 10` contains a magic number (10) which should be turned into a constant (ref. the beginning of the review).

I don't see any real use of the `FullHtml` property other than storing a reference so we'll change the scope and remove it.

The name of the `BodyHtml` property is misleading. It's not a html body. It contains our paragraphs so we'll name it accordingly. Same reason why we changed the name of the backing field earlier.

The name of the `Url` property is good so we'll keep that.

Since the backing fields of the properties are provided in the constructor we'll remove the setters and mark the properties read only.

```
Public ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection
    Get
        Return Me.m_paragraphs
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Url As String
    Get
        Return Me.m_url
    End Get
End Property
```

**VI** - Methods

> ```
> Private Sub DownloadHtml()
>
>     Dim HtmlWeb As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
>
>     FullHtml = New HtmlDocument
>
>     _BodyHtml = New HtmlNodeCollection(FullHtml.DocumentNode)
>
>     FullHtml = (HtmlWeb.Load(Url))
>     FullHtml.OptionFixNestedTags = True
>
>     BodyHtml = FullHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(BodyPath)
>
> End Sub
> ```

This method should be public and it should do all the heavy work. I also suggest you make it static (shared) and return an instance of our class based on downloaded data. Doing this makes it obvious why we made the constructor private and the properties read only.

```
Public Shared Function Download(url As String) As HtmlArticle

    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url)) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(url))
    End If

    Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
    Dim document As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)

    document.OptionFixNestedTags = True

    Dim paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(HtmlArticle.BodyPath)

    For index As Integer = (paragraphs.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
        If (Regex.Matches(paragraphs.Item(index).InnerText, HtmlArticle.WordPath).Count < HtmlArticle.MinLength) Then
            paragraphs.RemoveAt(index)
        End If
    Next

    Return New HtmlArticle(url, paragraphs)

End Function
```

**VII** - Improvments

So, how can we improve the performance of our class?

One possible solution is to add an overload which accepts multiple urls and run the download in parallel. The more cores your computer got, the better the result.

You might think that this requires a lot of coding but this is not the case. All you need is a thread safe list and the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method will do the rest.

```
Public Shared Function Download(urls As IEnumerable(Of String)) As List(Of HtmlArticle)

    If (urls Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(urls))
    End If

    Dim bag As New ConcurrentBag(Of HtmlArticle)
    urls.AsParallel().ForAll(Sub(url) bag.Add(HtmlArticle.Download(url)))
    Return bag.ToList()

End Function
```

---

**Result**

```
Public Class HtmlArticle

    Private Const BodyPath As String = "//body//p"
    Private Const WordPath As String = "[a-zA-Z]+"
    Private Const MinLength As Integer = 10

    Private m_url As String
    Private m_paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection

    Private Sub New(url As String, paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection)
        Me.m_url = url
        Me.m_paragraphs = paragraphs
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection
        Get
            Return Me.m_paragraphs
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Url As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_url
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Function Download(url As String) As HtmlArticle

        If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url)) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(url))
        End If

        Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
        Dim document As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)

        document.OptionFixNestedTags = True

        Dim paragraphs As HtmlNodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(HtmlArticle.BodyPath)

        For index As Integer = (paragraphs.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
            If (Regex.Matches(paragraphs.Item(index).InnerText, HtmlArticle.WordPath).Count < HtmlArticle.MinLength) Then
                paragraphs.RemoveAt(index)
            End If
        Next

        Return New HtmlArticle(url, paragraphs)

    End Function

    Public Shared Function Download(urls As IEnumerable(Of String)) As List(Of HtmlArticle)

        If (urls Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(urls))
        End If

        Dim bag As New ConcurrentBag(Of HtmlArticle)
        urls.AsParallel().ForAll(Sub(url) bag.Add(HtmlArticle.Download(url)))
        Return bag.ToList()

    End Function

End Class
```

**Usage**

```
Dim url As String = "url"
Dim singleArticle As HtmlArticle = HtmlArticle.Download(url)
```

```
Dim urls As New List(Of String)

urls.Add("url 1")
urls.Add("url 2")
urls.Add("url 3")
'etc...

Dim multipleArticles As List(Of HtmlArticle) = HtmlArticle.Download(urls)
```

Comment: Dude, you saved me. So many tips and suggestions, I'm stunned !!! Thank you so much, I realy learned a lot from your answer and will aplly it immediately.